# Chromeで閲覧している任意URLのhtmlタグに対して、なるべく簡単に「html{font-size:0.1em!important;}」を追加したい

Tags: html, css

**現状**
・Chromeで任意URLを閲覧
・右クリック後検証ページ開いた後、新規CSSルール追加

```
html{font-size:0.1em!important;}
```

**やりたいこと**
・毎回追加するCSSルールが同じなので、もっと簡単に(閲覧時のみ適用される)CSSルールを追加したい

**その他**
・元のソースコード自体には、変更を加えない前提です
・任意のURLに対してこちらの任意のタイミングで、フォントサイズを変更したい(すべてのURLに対して適用させたいわけではありません)

Comment: [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=ja)のような拡張機能を使用する方法では不十分でしょうか？

Comment: 拡張機能で大丈夫です。良さそうなので、ちょっと使い方を確認してみたいと思います。